# firebase push notifications not showing after app release

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications

They were showing a few days ago, after being released on Apple Store, the notifications don't show up anymore. I asked a lot of other people who dowloaded my app and they didn't receive any notifications either. The code and everything is fine because it was working great just before being released. Is there something I need to change with the message info?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you remember to upload a production APNS auth key / certificate? This could be the reason why it isn't working in production. (Image below)

#### Update:

After seeing your updated question it is clear that you haven't uploaded a production certificate. Doing this should make your push notifications work again.

[image]